# Is there a distinction between 我们决定早动身 and 我们决定早些出发 which mean "we decided on an early start"?

Tags: difference

One [jukuu.com](http://jukuu.com/show-%E5%86%B3%E5%AE%9A-8.html) example sentence:

> 我们决定早动身
>   We determined on an early start
>   <sub>(Wǒmen juédìng zǎo dòngshēn)</sub>

This breaks up into: [我们](http://dict.cn/%E6%88%91%E4%BB%AC) = we, [决定](http://dict.cn/%E5%86%B3%E5%AE%9A) = to decide, [早](http://dict.cn/%E6%97%A9) = early, [动身](http://dict.cn/%E5%8A%A8%E8%BA%AB) = to leave.

Another [jukuu.com](http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%87%BA%E5%8F%91) example sentence:

> 我们决定早些出发
>   We determined on an early start
>   <sub>(Wǒmen juédìng zǎo xiē chūfā)</sub>

This breaks up into: [我们](http://dict.cn/%E6%88%91%E4%BB%AC) = we, [决定](http://dict.cn/%E5%86%B3%E5%AE%9A) = to decide, [早](http://dict.cn/%E6%97%A9) = early, [些](http://dict.cn/%E4%BA%9B) = a few, [出发](http://dict.cn/%E5%87%BA%E5%8F%91) = start off.

In English, I think "we decided on an early start" sounds better.

**Question**: Is there a distinction between 我们决定早动身 and 我们决定早些出发?

In particular, I'm confused as to why 些 is used in the second example.  And I'm wondering if there's any difference between 动身 and 出发 in this context.

Comment: For the first, I'd use "早点动身". I don't see a difference without context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both 出发 and 动身 means "depart/ move out"

- 出发 literally means 'launch out' . It is more colloquial
- 动身 literally means 'move oneself' . It is more literary

> 动身 emphasizes on the action of 'moving oneself from his current location' (imply starting a journey to a destination)

Example:

- 动身去北京 (depart for the journey to Beijing)

> 出发 emphasizes on the action of 'moving out' .  You can 出发 to a journey or 出发 to fulfill a mission

Example:

- 出发去北京 (depart for the journey to Beijing)
- 出发去打仗 (off to fight a war)
- 出发去打猎 (off to hunting)

> We don't say '动身去打仗' or '动身去打猎'

~

> *我们决定早动身 and 我们决定早些出发 which mean “we decided on an early start”?*

Both mean "we decided to depart early."  The difference between 动身 and 出发 is stated above.

If you meant "off to a hunting trip", "off to fight a battle" or " depart for a sight seeing tour" , you can only use '出发'. If you meant "depart for a journey",  then either would be suitable.